# C++ How to split stringstream using mulitple delimiters

Tags: c++, delimiter, stringstream

How would I go about splitting up a stringstream into individual strings using multiple delimiters?
Right now it uses the default white space delimiter and I manually delete the first and last characters if they are anything other then alphanumeric.

The goal here is to read in a .cpp file and parse it for all the user idents that are not reserved words in C++.

It's working for benign examples but for stuff like this:

```
OrderedPair<map_iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& kvpair)
```

It is not working.  I'd like to be able to split OrderedPair into it's own word, map_iterator into it's own, bool, insert, const, value_type, and kvpair all into individual words.

How would I go about using "< > , ( & ) . -> *" as delimiters for my stringstream?

```
 while (getline(inFile, line)) {
    isComment = false;
    stringstream sstream(line);
    while (sstream >> word) {
        isCharLiteral = false;

        if (!isComment) {
            if (word[0] == '/' && word[1] == '/')
                isComment = true;
        }

        if (!isMultilineComment) {
            if (word[0] == '/' && word[1] == '*')
                isMultilineComment = true;
        }

        if (!isStringLiteral) {
            if (word[0] == '"')
                isStringLiteral = true;
        }

        if (!isCharLiteral) {
            if (word[0] == '\'' && word.back() == '\'')
                isCharLiteral = true;
        }

        if (isStringLiteral)
            if (word.back() == '"')
                isStringLiteral = false;

        if (isMultilineComment)
            if (word[0] == '*' && word[1] == '/')
                isMultilineComment = false;

        if (!isStringLiteral && !isMultilineComment && !isComment && !isCharLiteral) {
```

Comment: use something like boost::tokenizer http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm

Comment: First, there are character literals. You don't have to remember the ASCII table...

Comment: Is there any specific reason for advising not to use the ascii numbers over char literals?     Also for this specific task I can't use any other outside classes like boost::tokenizer. Just the standard included C++ things including the string class.

Comment: @momonkey 1. It's faster to type 'a', 'z', 'A', 'Z'. 
2. It's much more readable. 
3. Do not use "magic numbers". C++ is not a magic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use standard libraries, then I would suggest using `std::strtok()` to tokenize your string. You can pass any delimiters you like to `strtok()`. There is a reference for it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).

Since you are using a `string` datatype, for `strtok` to work properly, you'd have to copy your string into a null-terminated character array of sufficient length, and then call `strtok()` on that array.

Comment: How would I copy it into a null terminated char array? char* str[] = word; doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `char array[bigEnough]; strcpy(array, line.c_str());`

Answer (score 0):

C++ `std::istream` only provides basic input methods for the most common use cases. Here you can directly process the `std::string` with the methods `find_first_of` and `find_last_of` to identify either delimiters or non delimiters. It is easy to build something near the good old `strtok` but acting directly on a `std::string` instead of writing directly `\0` in the parsed string.

But for you are trying to achieve, you should take into accounts comments, string litteral, macros and pragmas that you should not search for indentifiers

Comment: I've updated my original post. I have checks in there for comments , multi line comments, char/string literals.  Which is why tokenizing it using strtok() doesn't seem to be a good idea for me.

Comment: @momonkey For nontrivial parsing needs, you probably should write your own tokenizer. I see that you have some multi-character delimiters. In my opinion, that is an indication for a custom tokenizer. So I'm suggesting that instead of relying on `stringstream's` ability to use various delimiters, you just read a line at a time and break it up yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to replace instances of the characters you want to be delimiters with whitespace. Then use your existing white space splitting setup.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Or get extra fancy with the regex and just match on the things you do want, and iterate through the matches.